# Google Distance Matrix API does not resolve 'London, ON'

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying out the Distance Matrix API but I can't make it work for London Ontario. It always comes back with London UK. My HTTP request is https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Ajax+ON&destinations=London,%20ON&key=

All other Candian cities are coming back fine. I can resort to Lat and Lon but I just wanted to check if there is a workaround by using the city name.

Thank you for your help!
MJ

Comment: I tried the request you provided, but it returns "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS". Would it be possible for you to provide another request that will demonstrate the issue? Thanks

Comment: @rafon thank you for your reply. Use the following request and notice how the API is switching "London, ON, Canada" with "London, UK". https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Ajax+ON&destinations=London,%20ON,%20Canada&key=

Using my key, I got the following result:
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "London, UK" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Ajax, ON, Canada" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}